# Eclipse - Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to run a java project called To-Do-O (source - http://www.ohloh.net/p/to-do-o/enlistments) After I loaded the projects into Eclipse and run the main.java, it returns the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot
>   load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

I tried adding -d32 as many of the solution suggests [[see iamge]](http://1drv.ms/1eiR2T3), but it returns another message

> Error: This java instance does not support a 32-bti JVM. Please install the desired version.

Does anyone have the fix??

Comment: Is this a Mac? The Java 7 on the Mac does not support 32 bit.

Comment: It's on Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 1):

Referring to http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/SWT-libraries-on-64-bit-JVM-td91066.html
You should either download SWT 64 bit, or run JVM with -d32 option. If you are on a mac, with java 7 or 8, you might get an error message: "This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM". Of course nothing restricts you from using an old java version:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -d32 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Uninstall your Current Java

2: Download/Install the 64 Bit Version of Java

3: Start Your Eclipse Again :-)